# Shower niche in larger cavity

Tags: shower, tile

I’m redoing the tiles for a 3’x3’ shower stall. It’s in the corner of a room, with the side wall an exterior wall, and the wall with shower head is a dividing wall between condos. There is a half wall as the 3rd wall. I’m looking to install a niche, but I don’t want to put it in the exterior wall, so I’m planning to put the niche in the shower head wall. But that wall has non-standard stud spacing, so I’m going to build out the niche instead of using a pre-built niche box like ezniche. Howeever, in pulling out the insulation I discovered there isn’t drywall directly behind the studs in the corner but rather a larger empty cavity (see pics, its small, to the right directly behind the shower faucet studs begins a cinder block wall). In total the depth is about 10”. Id like to built it here but I’m a bit worried about (a) how to build the back of the niche, so I don’t have to build all the way back the 10” and (b) whether there is any issue with the exterior wall being next to this cavity, causing cold air to come in through the niche.
Any advice welcome[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you planning on using on the walls and for waterproofing? If using kerdiboard you can just make the niche out of that and glue the panels together with kerdifix. It doesn't need to be supported although some blocking for it to sit on wouldn't hurt

Comment: Hmm, using Durock with AquaGuard for waterproofing, so maybe that wouldn’t quite work. After posting I was thinking it might not be too bad to add blocking behind the studs to support the niche at the back and limit depth (though more of a pain than the Kerdi solution). What about being next to the exterior wall in this cavity? Do you think I will have issues with cold?

Comment: You could get away with adding two horizontal 2x4 blocks and screwing a piece of durock to the back of the rectangle formed, then adding short 3.5" wide sections of stock to form the niche. Tape and fill with thinset when you cover your other seams prior to the aquaguard